# What is "Failed to check extensions updates: Unknown Error," and how do I get rid of it

Tags: gnome, firefox, notification

Every time I start Firefox, I get this message:
[image]

What does it mean and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Probably because https://extensions.gnome.org/ (or your internet) was down. Check after some time.

Comment: It's been happening for the past couple of days, so it can't be that. Also when I try to update my extensions, I get an error.

Comment: Could you update your question with the error message(s) you get while updating your extensions?